# Chrome Extensions - number of tabs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I get how many tabs were open and number of the current tab in the browser?

Answer (score 4):

Use `chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow().length` and then

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(Tab t) {
  // current tab index
  alert(t.index);
})
```

**UPDATE**

[`getAllInWindow`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getAllInWindow) is deprecated since Chrome 33. You should use [`query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) with `{windowId: chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT}` or `{currentWindow: true}`.

Answer (score 4):

Since Chrome 16, use https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query .

Example:

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(foundTabs) {
        var tabsCount = foundTabs.length;
        console.info("tabsCount = " + tabsCount);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this extension: OLD! [Tabs Counter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-counter/ibokmmioadhomkeikgbfenloopldkcoi).

EDIT:
after 9 years someone downvoted my answer. I suppose because the link above seems to not work anymore. Anyway, there's another link with a similar extension. Check it out: [Chrome Tab Counter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-tab-counter/fhnegjjodccfaliddboelcleikbmapik)

If you want to inspect the source code, a simple search would have land you to this: [GitHub of Chrome Tab Counter](https://github.com/fero8/chrome-tab-counter)